# Mapbox: is it possible to update layer hierarchy?

Tags: mapbox

I have a Mapbox with my own layers, says labels of towns and landmarks...

say I want to highlight one specific landmark and I want to move its z-index higher because otherwise, it would overlap with some other elements...

Can I use `map.setLayoutProperty` or is there anything else that I can do?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, you're looking for a way to change z-index of some **layer** above another layer. (**not** some **feature** above another feature). Here it the way:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#movelayer

```
map.moveLayer(yourLandmarkLayerId, someAnotheLayerId);
```

If you would like just to move landmark layer to top of layer hierarchy:

```
map.moveLayer(yourLandmarkLayerId);
```

P.S. For moving layer, you should know it's ID:

```
var layers = map.getStyle().layers;
var layerId = layers[i].id;
```

Comment: Note, that `moveLayer` doesn't change order of event handlers execution. So you can't change layers this way to make `stopPropagation()` or `preventDefault()` work. It's not very intuitive, see the issue: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5783

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking to do it on **android**, the simplest way to do it is to remove the layer and add it again above or below another layer. I do not find a better way:

```
    /**
     * Remove the target layer and add it again above the specific layer
     */
    fun moveLayerAvobe(layer: Layer, breakpointLayerID: String, style: Style) {
        // Remove Layer
        style.removeLayer(layer)

        // Add it again
        style.addLayerAbove(layer, breakpointLayerID)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On MapBox SDK v10 reordering layers looks like this:

```
mapboxMap.getStyle()
    ?.moveStyleLayer(layerId, LayerPosition(/*above*/null, /*below*/null, /*at*/zIndex))
```

In this example we don't use `above` and `below` params, sending the layer right to the position designated by `zIndex` value.